# How to create a query that create sum of previous and current year total amount, base on multiple rows data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to create a query based on the date, I want to sum the credit and debit based on the year of the transaction_line and display it as total_previous (date within 2021) and total_current (date within 2022). Below is what I do and what is the expected result.

transaction_lines table:

| account_id | date | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1021 | 2021-11-08 | 100 | 0 |
| 1021 | 2022-01-02 | 107 | 0 |
| 1021 | 2022-04-22 | 0 | 50 |
| 1021 | 2022-04-22 | 12 | 0 |

What I got currently:

| account_id | total_previous | total_current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1021 | 0 | -169 |

Expected result:

| account_id | total_previous | total_current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1021 | -100 | -69 |

The query that I executed:

```
SELECT 
    account_id,
    date,
    debit,
    credit,
    IF(date >= '2021-01-01'
            AND date <= '2021-12-31',
        - COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0),
        0) AS total_previous,
    IF(date >= '2022-01-01'
            AND date <= '2022-12-31',
        - COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0),
        0) AS total_current
FROM
    transaction_lines
WHERE
    account_id = '1021'
        AND date >= '2021-01-01'
        AND date <= '2022-12-31';
```

I already work on this for a full day, thus I need help to justify if it is actually achievable. If it is possible, please advise me on what is wrong with my query.

Comment: seems like you are calculating it wrong you need to sum the debit and credit amounts separately for each year and subtract the debit amount from the credit amount for each year., i have corrected it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8g1ts2NVMkLeWaMvzREAP2/0) please check

Comment: Note that the key here is to not mix columns like date with aggregate functions like sum; when you do that, the columns will have a value from an arbitrary row of those being grouped (or using modern MySQL settings, you will get an error).  Put all references to data inside the aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sas8aGXEj6xutqHpJs6LmQ/0):

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  account_id INT NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  debit DECIMAL(10,2),
  credit DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO transactions (account_id, date, debit, credit) 
VALUES 
  (1021, '2021-11-08', 100.00, 0.00),
  (1021, '2022-01-02', 107.00, 0.00),
  (1021, '2022-04-22', 0.00, 50.00),
  (1021, '2022-04-22', 12.00, 0.00);

SELECT account_id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2021 THEN -Debit+Credit END) AS total_previous
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2022 THEN -Debit+Credit END) AS total_current
FROM transactions
GROUP BY account_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the year in the query, you can make the query dynamic so that it you can see the current_total and prev_total for multiple years.

```
SELECT 
    current.account_id,
    current.current_year,
    current.current_total,
    prev.current_year as prev_year,
    prev.current_total AS prev_total
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t2.account_id,
            DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') AS current_year,
            SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit) AS current_total
    FROM
        transactions t2
    GROUP BY t2.account_id , DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y')) `current`
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t2.account_id,
            DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') AS current_year,
            SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit) AS current_total
    FROM
        transactions t2
    GROUP BY t2.account_id , DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y')) `prev` ON (current.account_id = prev.account_id
        AND (current.current_year - 1) = prev.current_year)
```

Then when you want for a certain year you can just add a where clause
e.g where current.current_year = 2021